# Comparing data in Array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to make a comparison from the data that comes with JSON. That's what I wrote for it.

```
$packages[0][0] = "5678"; // on the way
$packages[0][1] = "3098"; // checkpoint
$packages[0][2] = "4331"; // accept

if (array_key_exists($packages[0][2], $data[6])) {
    $packageID= 1;
} else if (array_key_exists($packages[0][1], $data[6]) == true) {
    $packageID= 5; 
} else if (array_key_exists($packages[0][0], $data[6]) == true) {
    $packageID= 10; 
} else {
    $packageID=0;
}
```

For example JSON:

```
* Array
    (
        [0] => xxx
        [1] => yyy
        [2] => xxx
        [3] => yyy
        [4] => xxx
        [5] => yyy
        [6] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1234
                [1] => 5678
                [2] => 9012 
            )

    )
```

`PackageID` always comes out to `0`.

What could be the reason?

Comment: May I ask what are these magic numbers `1,5,10,0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re using [`array_key_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php), but you should be using [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). The values you’re searching are elements, not keys.

```
$packages[0][0] = "5678"; // on the way
$packages[0][1] = "3098"; // checkpoint
$packages[0][2] = "4331"; // accept

if (in_array($packages[0][2], $data[6])) {
    $packageID= 1;
} else if (in_array($packages[0][1], $data[6]) == true) {
    $packageID= 5; 
} else if (in_array($packages[0][0], $data[6]) == true) {
    $packageID= 10; 
} else {
    $packageID=0;
}
```